# Illegal offset type yii2

Tags: yii2

I am a newbie to Yii framework. I did download extension [Image-cropper](https://github.com/karpoff/yii2-crop-image-upload) from Github and somehow i got an error 'Illegal offset type' on my model. I don't have any ideas on what is the problem. But it seems that my rules method is a bit wrong, and i don't know what. The **error** is on **'picture1'** .

```
public function rules()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    return [

        [['picture1'] => [
            'class' => 'developit\jcrop\actions\Upload',
            'url' => '/common/files/',
            'path' => Yii::getAlias('@web/img/1/memoriam/'),
            'name' => Yii::$app->user->id,
        ],],
        [['name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_decease','gender','background'], 'required'],
        [['date_of_birth', 'date_of_decease', 'funeral_date', 'post_dt', 'edit_dt'], 'safe'],
        [['epitaph', 'biography', 'obituary_message'], 'string','on'=>['create', 'update']],
        [['owner_id', 'background','page'], 'integer','on'=>['create', 'update']],
        [['owner_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['owner_id' => 'ID']],
        [['name', 'place_of_birth', 'funeral_address'], 'string', 'max' => 255,'on'=>['create', 'update']],
        [['gender', 'category', 'privacy_status'], 'string', 'max' => 1,'on'=>['create', 'update']],
        //[['picture1'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],
        [['owner_id'], 'default', 'on'=>['create','update'], 'value'=>$session['UserID']],
        [['post_dt'], 'default', 'on'=>['create'], 'value'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')],


    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it on wrong place. You should attach it to model behaviors, not in rules.

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => CropImageUploadBehavior::class,
                'attribute' => 'picture1',
                'scenarios' => ['insert', 'update'],
                'path' => '@webroot/upload/docs',
                'url' => '@web/upload/docs',
                'ratio' => 1,
                'crop_field' => 'photo_crop',
                'cropped_field' => 'photo_cropped',
                    ],
        ];
    }
```